# Magento link to skin image from app folder

Tags: html, css, magento, theming

I'm trying to hard code social icons in

```
projectname/app/design/frontend/projectname/default/template/page/html/footer.phtml
```

The html

```
<a src="../">facebook</a>
```

What is the correct way to link the img file in the theme skin folder

```
skin/frontend/projectName/default/images/webicons/socialIcon.png
```

**The problem is how do I link from the app folder to the skin folder?**

Answer (score 11):

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/webicons/socialicon.jpg') ?>" alt=""/>
```

OR

```
<img src="{{skin url=images/webicons/socialicon.jpg}}" alt="" />
```

This will help you to get the proper image from skin folder.

**I hope this will help you.**

Answer (score 3):

```
img src = "<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/webicons/socialicon.jpg')?>"/>Facebook
```

The code above would get the URL of the file “your_image_name.jpg” placed in your skin directory. Code works for both front and backend purposes. Hope it helps.